# Migrating from DataSet / DataTable to queues

Tags: c#

I have a log page in a winform app that shows the background processes and sorts out the messages into message "queues" using DataSet and DataTables.  As new processes are discovered, a new log is created.  This works pretty good, however I have a memory leak.  I've been researching switching over to "Queues".

(rough copy/paste due to complexity and length)

```
DataSet dsLogs = new DataSet("Logs");
....
[Message Queue accept new message, the following creates a new tab with an icon to click and watch queue - accept "oLogObject" from message queue]

            if (!dsLogs.Tables.Contains(szTableName)) // add table in
            {
                DataTable dtNew = new DataTable(szTableName);
                dtNew.Columns.Add("EventDate", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("Function", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("IsError", typeof(bool));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("LongMessage", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("RecID", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("Thread", typeof(string));
                dtNew.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));

                MenuAdmin.btnProcessStatus NewPanel = new MenuAdmin.btnProcessStatus();
                NewPanel.SetProcess(oLogObject.Process);
                NewPanel.SetThread(oLogObject.Thread);
                NewPanel.Name = szTableName;
                NewPanel.SetName(szTableName);
                NewPanel.Click += NewPanel_Click;

                dsLogs.Tables.Add(dtNew);
             }

             DataRow drRow = dsLogs.Tables[szTableName].NewRow();
             AddRow(oLogObject, szTableName); // adds the current log object to the table
```

So my issue with Queues is that I can't use them with a DataSet so I can't name / refer to them by name like this:

```
DataRow drRow = dsLogs.Tables[szTableName].NewRow();
```

Is this possible and what is the terminology called that would accomplish this in Queues?

Answer (score 1):

Queues are not able to directly use DataSet/DataTable data.  Queues are a generic collection (.NET version in System.Collections.Generic namespace) so you would probably want to create a class (something like AppEvent) with all the fields that you have defined in the DataTable.  When you add a new item to the Queue you would be adding a new object of the AppEvent class.

I hope that this clears things up.